# Reload a JQGrid after Jquery Date Picker selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using a JQGrid in one of my ASP.NET projects where the grid shows a list of items that are sortable/filterable (That's all working fine)

The only problem im having with it is, one of the columns is a date field so I have the filter textbox using the date picker (using the below options)

```
{ name:'Due',
  index:'Due', 
  width:100, 
  align:"center",
  searchoptions:{
      dataInit:function(el){
          $(el).datepicker({dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy'});
      }
   }
 }
```

But when I select a date from the date picker it's not refreshing the grid automatically (like the dropdowns do) I have to click the textbox again and press enter.

Is there a way to fix this?

jqGrid  3.5 beta

Comment: thanks for the formatting seth...

Comment: np...let me know if I screwed anything up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't used JQGrid, but from the documentation you should be able to do something like this:

```
{
    name:'Due',
    index:'Due', 
    width:100, 
    align:"center",
    searchoptions:{
        dataInit:function(el){
            $(el).datepicker({
                dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy',
                onSelect: function(dateText, inst){ $("#grid_id")[0].triggerToolbar(); }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to change the `#grid_id` to the selector that matches your grid.

**Updated:** Changed `$("#grid_id").trigger("reloadGrid");` to `$("#grid_id")[0].triggerToolbar();`. Tested this on the [jqGrid 3.5b demos](http://www.trirand.com/jqgrid35/jqgrid.html) and it works.

Comment: Hey Jason, that kinda works, it triggers the reloading of the grid, but not with the new data... any other ideas?

Comment: I've updated the solution. It worked on the demo I tested it on!

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help, but how did you find that?

Comment: I looked through the source code of jqGrid until I found what I was looking for - it wasn't documented anywhere that I could see! I would imagine that this is a temporary workaround until the developers add this to be the default jqGrid functionality - you might like to suggest it to them?

Comment: This does work, but if you want to clear the toolbar and search w/o parameters it requires a convoluted combination of selecting it (which brings up the picker), clearing the text, hitting Enter to get a fresh reload, then hitting Escape to clear the picker.