# Show a date field in rails 3 using a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, calendar

I want a select or a text field which allows one to select a date by clicking on a popup calendar. My solution already works with calendar_date_select but the problem is that I need to replace protptype plugins with jquery ones, so I need to get rid of teh calendar_date_select and use some jquery plugin for similar funnctionality, but usin Rails 3. Is there such a plugin or gem available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include jquery UI in your project and use [Jquery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/). Will work like a charm what ever version you are using as its totally Javascript HTML and css. :-)

All you need to do it. Include Jquery Ui in you project which you can download from [here](http://jqueryui.com/download) and this JavaScript code. You can remove unnecessary features which u don't need.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#id_of_my_datepicker_text_box" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used [JQuery Tools Dateinput](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/dateinput/index.html). The whole (maximum size) JQuery Tools library with tabs, overlays, tooltips and others weights about 15k gzipped and can be obtained through CDN. Here is an example with dateinput.

```
<!-- HTML5 date input -->
<input type="date" />

<!-- make it happen -->
<script>
  $(":date").dateinput();
</script>
```

JQuery UI is another great option but it weights ~200kb gzipped. But if you decide to remove some features you couldn't use google CDN.

Answer (score 1):

yup

Datepicker works gr8.[Datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186284/reload-a-jqgrid-after-jquery-date-picker-selection)

Just have a look ,it's surely gonna help.It's totally configurable as per your needs.